# IndexOutOfRangeException for some strange reasons

Tags: c#, arrays

I came across this strange IndexOutOfRangeException exception. The code I am working with was originally a C code, I have managed to translate it to C#

So I the followin loop gives me the error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    L[0] = new double[]{ T[0] + rxp[0][i] - (p[0][i])
}
```

According to the 'Locals' tab, rxp has only 3 'children' with only 1 items / child. 
So I guess the problem is here:

```
void getrxp()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        rxp[0] = new double[]{ M[0][0] * (re[0][i]) + M[0][1] * (re[1][i]) + M[0][2] * 0};
        rxp[1] = new double[]{ M[1][0] * (re[0][i]) + M[1][1] * (re[1][i]) + M[1][2] * 0};
        rxp[2] = new double[]{ M[2][0] * (re[0][i]) + M[2][1] * (re[1][i]) + M[2][2] * 0};
    }
}
```

Am I getting this to to create a `double rxp[3][6];` array wrong or there is something else?

The original code looks like this (C):

```
void getrxp()
{
  for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    rxp[0][i] = M[0][0]*(re[0][i])+M[0][1]*(re[1][i])+M[0][2]*0;
    rxp[1][i] = M[1][0]*(re[0][i])+M[1][1]*(re[1][i])+M[1][2]*0;
    rxp[2][i] = M[2][0]*(re[0][i])+M[2][1]*(re[1][i])+M[2][2]*0;  
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you think `rxp[0][i]` in C is equivalent to `rxp[0]` in C#?

Comment: According to the C function that he's trying to convert to c# to, he's not trying to create an array of arrays. So, duplicate mark is wrong.

Comment: Well this if you take a look at Jagged Arrays at MSDN, you can see why I've made it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a 2-dimensional array, the syntax should be `double [,] rxp = new double[3,6];`. Here's the detailed documentation of [Multidimensional Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) at MSDN.

Comment: I thought I should use Jagged Arrays... This did the trick.